# Views entity reference field

Tags: entities, views

I am trying to create a news content type which can display related content.

In the news content type I have an Entity Reference field with unlimited values, which is used to select the nodes which should be "Related" to the current node.

I have created a view and managed to get it to display all content which is "related" to ANY node with a content type of news using the relationship setting, but i can't manage to get it to display content related to a specific node.

What am I doing wrong? I can provide more info if I have missed anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use eva module. visit this [link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/72355/views-with-entity-reference) (comment 3), I tested this solution and it works.